# HOW TO ADD ONE MORE COLUMN IN django.contrib.auth.models from User in django rest framework

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Actually i tried to authenticate my django project using JWT django.contrib.auth.models from User model and need to add one more column in user model but i cannot able to add one column don't no why?

Comment: If you are wondering why this question has been down voted it seems to lack clarity and information. Try updating your question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Change your User model to a custom User model that inherits the Django user model and add whatever you need there, don't forget to edit the settings file, here is a full example of doing the above [Custom User Model](https://wsvincent.com/django-tips-custom-user-model/).

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to add more field in your django user model, then you have to write new custom user model which should be extended from AbstractUser class

Example:- 

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


Add one line in settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.User' # where custom user model is defined


Then execute the command:-

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate
```